# Does this supremum equal infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is a generalization of the previous question [Does this infimum tend to infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116244/does-this-infinum-tend-to-infinity)

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function satisfying $$\sup _{x>0}f(x,y)=+\infty\quad\text{for each fixed }y\in\mathbb{R}.$$ Further, let $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a compact set and define $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=\inf_{y\in\mathcal{I}}f(x,y)$

Is it true that $$\sup _{x>0}g(x)=+\infty$$

?

My initial guess is that it isn't true. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x,y)=|y- e^{-|x|}|e^{x^2}$, then for each fixed $y$ it clearly grows quickly with $x$. However, with $I=[0,1]$, we have $g(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$.
$$f(x,y):=\begin{cases}\sin(yx)x&\text{ for }y\in I\\\sin(\pi x/2)x&\text{ for }y<\pi/2\\\sin(3\pi x/2)x&\text{ for }y>3\pi/2\end{cases}$$